# Explanation needed for Hammack's Introduction to Proof Example 1.2 {7a+3b : a,b ∈ Z}

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding what Hammack means with this and how he arrived at the result.

> Solution: This set contains all numbers of form 7a + 3b, where a and b
> are integers. Each such number 7a +3b is an integer, so A contains only
> integers. But which integers? If n is any integer, then n = 7n +3(−2n), so
> n = 7a+3b where a = n and b = −2n. Therefore n ∈ A. We’ve now shown that
> A contains only integers, and also that every integer is an element of A.
> Consequently A = Z.

For example, why is 7 and 3 used, is there any relevance to these numbers? How can n = 7a+3b, and a = n, which is part of n, doesn't that mean the a is going to be n, so it's somehow recursive? I'm pretty lost with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about this set $S = \{7a+3b\,:\, a,b\in {\mathbb Z}\}$. One way to think about it  is that it contains all integers of the form: a multiple of 7 plus a multiple of 3. So $10$ is in $S$ since it's $7+3$ and $4 \in S$ since $4= 7 + (-3)$ (and 7 is a multiple of $7$, while $-3$ is a multiple of $3$.

We're trying to understand which integers are in $S$, and the answer turns out to be pretty simple---they all are. The book's proof of this is of the form: you give me and integer $n$ and I'll tell you what multiples of $7$ and $3$ to use. As Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla says, one possibility for these numbers are to use $7n$ and $-6n$. So if you want to get $n=5$ you can get $5$ as $5 = 7\times 5 - 6\times 5$. If you want to get $n$ you can write $n = 7n-6n$, so $n$ is a multiple of $7$ plus a multiple of $3$ and therefore $n\in S$.

As to why $7$ and $3$ are used, well, it's an example of a theme in (modern) algebra. In general the elements of $S_{k,\ell} = \{ak+b\ell\,:\, a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ are all multiples of $\gcd(k,\ell)$. Our $S$ is $S_{7,3}$ and we've shown that $S_{7,3}$ is the set of all multiples of $1$, i.e., $S=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered, it really helped.

Answer (score 2):

> How can n = 7a+3b, and a = n, which is part of n, doesn't that mean the a is going to be n, so it's somehow recursive?

It is **not** recursive.

Consider $a,b$ as functions of $n$. Namely: given $n$ you have $a(n) = n$, $b(n) = −2n$.

> For example, why is 7 and 3 used, is there any relevance to these numbers?

The important fact is that $\gcd(7,3) = 1$. See [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Answer (score 1):

$7$ and $3$ are not randomly selected. Hammack knows something about these two integers: he knows that $$\exists u\in \mathbb Z, \exists v\in \mathbb Z \text{ s.t. 7u+3v=1}$$
This is what we call a *Bézout identity*. Here with $u=1 $and $v=-2$.

That's how he built his demonstration. Nothing complicated: read it again quietly.

Maybe it will help you to know that there are different cases such as
$$\{35a+15b:a,b \in \mathbb Z\}=5\mathbb Z$$
set of multiples of $5$.